# difference of Cauchy sequences is Cauchy

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a normed space and let $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ be Cauchy sequences on $X$. Show that $z_n=\mid\mid x_n-y_n\mid\mid$ is also a Cauchy sequence on $\mathbb{R}.$

My answer:

$ | z_n-z_m | = | \ \ ||x_n-y_n||-||x_m-y_m|| \ \ | \leq ||x_n-y_n||+||x_m-y_m||$

i stuck at this step. I need hint.

Comment: $$\lvert \lVert a\rVert - \lVert b\rVert \rvert \leqslant \lVert a-b\rVert$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't need to mix the x's and y's:

$$||z_n-z_m||=||x_n-y_n-x_m+y_m||\le||x_n-x_m||+||y_m-y_n||\le\ldots$$

Comment: is it possible ? i dont get it

Comment: @andii, for any given $\;\epsilon>0\;$ there exist $\;N_1,N_2\in\Bbb N\;$ s.t. $$\begin{cases}n,m>N_1\implies ||x_n-x_m||<\frac\epsilon2\\n,m>N_2\implies ||y_n-y_m||<\frac\epsilon2\end{cases}$$ Now just take $\;N:=\max\{N_1,N_2\}\;$ and use my answer above